# Como ativar o link de acordo com a navegação do Slide

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-3, slide

Eu tenho um slide feito com Bootstrap 3 e eu preciso que passar as imagens do slide, o menu fique com as letras verdes e com o contorno para identificar a navegação, mostrando a onde que a pessoa está.
Hoje quando eu passo o mouse em cima acontece o efeito de mudança devido ao css e quando clico em dos link, o slide leva para a foto correspondente.
A imagem abaixo mostra o efeito mas o slide não está acompanhando a imagem. Gostaria que acompanhasse.
https://github.com/FabricioDev/LayoutResponsivo
ou https://gist.github.com/FabricioDev/8a03434e26a3c5ffecf04e3fee80375c
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca o código fonte ou parte relevante eu não sei é o arquivo deve ser modificado.

Comment: @rray, você pode me dar uma força? Coloquei o código no Gits.